# Will a large amount of constant-power loads make an electrical grid unstable?

Tags: power-electronics, mains, power-grid

Over time, a larger proportion of electronics are constant-power loads, while they used to be constant-resistance. Will this lead to an unstable grid? If not, why not?

Constant power loads at home are battery chargers, TVs, many appliances.

In a constant-resistance environment, the grid is self-regulating to a certain extent, as if power generation cannot match power consumption, then a slight drop in voltage would reduce the consumption.

In a constant power environment, this self-regulation would not exist, as a slight drop in generator voltage would just lead to an increased current draw and a constant power consumption. This sounds like it would lead to a run-away process if left unchecked.

Comment: Related: [Producers consumers balance in the grid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/464569/producers-consumers-balance-in-the-grid)

Comment: Not an answer to the core question about the effect of constant-power loads, but all these loads are not that big amount compared to other loads. See https://www.epa.gov/energy/electricity-customers - appliances and electronics are not the dominant consumer, and even for that washing machines, dryers, refrigerators and ovens totally outclass TVs and battery chargers. Boiling water for a single cup of coffee or tea takes more energy than fully charging your phone.

Comment: @Peteris Datapoint: 1 kWh = 850 litre-degrees-C for water. So rising say 1 litre (4 standard cups) of water from say 15C to 100C = 85c x 1 litre = 85 litre.degrees = 0.1 kWh = 100 Wh. Charging a phone battery of say 3.3 Ah x 5V from supply at say 80% overall efficient (typically TWO smps in series) = about 20 Wh. So yes, even an iPad 10 Ah battery takes less than a kettle boil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, potentially a lot of constant-power loads will destabilize a feedback
loop that keeps the grid voltage steady.   This is because constant power
is symbolized by 
$$power = V \times I = constant$$
 while resistive (like a heater) loads
are symbolized by $$power = V \times I = V^2 \times constant$$

The grid must deliver extra power whenever it sees a voltage dip.
The heater load makes a V versus I function that has a strong
power decrease when V goes low, i.e. it helps the grid
feedback control (lower power load is like higher power supply).   The constant-power load, however, has a 
proportional current-load INCREASE when V goes low, which means
it requires a larger current increase than the voltage deficiency
alone would indicate.   It is thus fighting the power-grid voltage
regulation mechanism.

Fighting is normal, but you don't want the power-grid to lose that fight.

Comment: Info only: Different scenario - same result. A DC feed to Sardinia ended up in instability with the tail wagging the dog  due to load-supply dynamics. Long ago.